# Creating a dll containing many namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

Suppose I have a bunch of namespaces:

```
SuperNamespace.namespace1
SuperNamespace.namespace2
SuperNamespace.namespace3
SuperNamespace.namespace4
...
SuperNamespace.namespaceN
```

Each namespace has its own project and each project creates its own dll file:

```
SuperNamespace.namespace1.dll
SuperNamespace.namespace2.dll
SuperNamespace.namespace3.dll
SuperNamespace.namespace4.dll
...
SuperNamespace.namespaceN.dll
```

I like this design because it allows developers to use only the code that they need.  Sometimes having a bunch of dll's can be a bit cumbersome and annoying.  I would like to create a SuperNamespace.dll which contains all of the namespaces.  That way, a developer has the option to use what he/she needs or just take the big dll file, i.e. SuperNamespace.dll containing all libraries:

```
SuperNamespace.namespace1
SuperNamespace.namespace2
SuperNamespace.namespace3
SuperNamespace.namespace4
...
SuperNamespace.namespaceN
```

Is there a way to do this in a C# Visual Studio 2010 solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply create one large project with all sources unless there are other reasons to keep separate assemblies.

In later case I'd still create one project that includes everythin in addition to small projects before going ILMerge route as Mith Wheat suggested. You can easily create  new project from a lot of files using File->New project from source (may need higher version of Visual Studio for that, defintely not Express ones).

There is no restrictions how many C# namespaces can be used in in one assembly (DLL). You can find many examples in .Net framework itself - i.e. many of System.* namespaces come from the same assembly.

Opposite is true also - same namespace can come from multiple assemblies.

Note that in compiled code there is no such thing as "namespace" - it becomes part of class/struct/enum name.